# Redirect user back to the private page after they have logged in

Tags: users, redirection, authentication-authorization

On my site I have a private page that can only be accessed when the user is logged in. If they aren't logged in they are directed to the login page.

I want to redirect them back to that page after they've logged in

I've tried a lot of solutions already listed on here including: logindestination and logintoboggan.

Every time the person logs in they are always directed to their user page no matter what I change in logintoboggan/logindestination

I tried creating a rule but was getting a 404. I'm not sure what to put in the PHP Evaluation field in the redirect action.

I've added this to my template file

```
global $user;
    if ($user->uid == 0){
        print l("Login","user/login",array('query' =>     drupal_get_destination()));
    }
else{
print l("Logout","user/logout",array('query' => drupal_get_destination()));
}
```

And then in logindestination I added

```
$destination = drupal_get_destination();
print $destination;
```

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: *On my site I have a private page that can only be accessed when the user is logged in.* Just to understand, I have one question. What is the meaning of private page here? If it is viewable by non-logged in user, how can it be private. You mean that, non-logged in user can view but cannot comment?

Comment: The page being private means that the user must be logged in to access.

Comment: Would you let me know which module did you use to make the private page. Why I am asking so I can try on my trial site. As this issue I faced and I came up with solution with logindestination+logintoboggan. Because my solution can work on normal page for comment access but might not work on page which is entirely non-accessible. I guess, you have set a page, which states like "Login to access this page".

Comment: I didn't use a module to make the page private. I wrote the code myself for this. function formtest_user_logged_in(){
 
 if(user_is_logged_in()){
  
  drupal_goto('form');
 }
 else
 {
  drupal_goto('user?destination=form');
 }
}

Comment: function formtest_form() {
 if(user_is_logged_in()){
  return drupal_get_form('formtest_my_form');
  }
  
  else
  {
drupal_goto( 'user/login',drupal_get_destination() );
   
   } // <----- this is the name of  our form
}

Comment: I can't figure it out, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For logindestination to work properly all you need to do is add an entry using `<current>` as the redirect location.  Leave the "Redirect to Page" option as `Internal page or external URL`.  This configuration will send a user back to the page they were trying to access before being sent to the login page.

[image]

Comment: I ended up changing my code on my custom page so that the access control is 'user_is_logged_in'. This fixed the issue I was having with LoginToboggan and now everythiing is working perfectly. Thanks for the help